Chunking text within transformers pipeline
I am creating a conversation chain in langchain. The chain queries on a FAISS vectorstore and responds to questions asked about the vectorsrore.
To have precise responses, I need to vectorize the document page by page. Obviously, this will force the LLM model to truncate the text which is less than ideal for my use case.
I am trying to integrate the chunking step in the code bellow. In a way that, the vectorstore has the whole page encoded but once the page is passed to pipeline, it will be divided to chunks.
Is there a standard way to do that? Or should I become creative and create an extension of the class pipeline?
The following is my code:
`    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True)
self.conversation = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline("text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, model_kwargs, framework = 'pt')),
retriever=self.vectorstore.as_retriever(),
memory=memory,
verbose = True,
max_tokens_limit=None)`

